# Yii Controller Naming Convention

Tags: php, linux, apache, yii

I have a controller named `CategoryAdminController.php` which can be accessed by `{siteurl}/categoryadmin/index` in my localhost which is on a Windows machine. But when I try to launch it in my remote server which is on a Linux platform, it is unable to load the page. But when I rename my controller as `CategoryadminController.php` (and the class name accordingly), it is working fine.

Is there any way to load the page while keeping the original name in the controller (ie: `CategoryAdminController.php`)

According to Yii guide, seems it is not possible.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.convention

Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

To keep Controller names and Action names CamelCased and working on Linux, you need to add dash between each word in the URL:

```
"{siteurl}/category-admin/index"  -> CategoryAdminController->indexAction()

"{siteurl}/category-admin/my-way"  -> CategoryAdminControllern->myWayAction()
```

This will work both on **Linux** and **Windows**.

**Windows** reads files and folders **case-insensitive**. And often *hides* some of the mistakes.

The common issue comes when you develop on Windows ... and create a link `categoryadmin` the OS will find be happy to give you a file like
`CaTegoRYadmiNcontroller.php` ignoring the capitalization.

But when you deploy the same code and files on Linux you will get `File Not Found` exceptions.
So, better stick to the convention.

Comment: this is the right answer and should be selected  +1

Comment: Also applies to Yii2

Answer (score 0):

It is case-sensitive for a file's name when on a Linux OS, but not on Windows. Did you try to access it: `{siteurl}/categoryAdmin/index` ?

Comment: Hi, Thank your for your reply. Yes, it's case sensitive only in Linux. yeah, I tried {siteurl}/categoryAdmin/index and it was working. But I need it to be worked even for lowercase url. (ie: {siteurl}/categoryadmin/index)

Comment: Sorry for my late reply,you can set rewrite rules in you .htaccess file.

Comment: i.e.: `RewriteRule ^categoryadmin/index$                                                 /index.php?r=categoryAdmin/index [NC,L,QSA]`

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the URLs by using the [urlManager](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUrlManager). In your case you can use the following code:

```
'urlManager' => array(
    'urlFormat' => 'path',
    'showScriptName' => FALSE,
    'rules' => array(
        'categoryadmin/<action:\w+>' => 'categoryAdmin/<action>'
    ),
),
```